# What does $\chi$ represent in this context.

Tags: analysis, notation

just to check what does $\chi$ represent in this context:

Let $\phi_j\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\chi_Q\leq\phi_j\leq\chi_{\lambda Q}$, where $\lambda>1$.

$\lambda Q$ is defined as the scaling of the cube $Q$ with scale factor $\lambda$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is the characteristic function or indicator function of a measurable set. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: For a set $A$, $\chi_A$ is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ elsewhere.